# Unable to login to Facebook when running App locally

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, local

I have the facebook javascript in my page. When I click on the button, I get this error

> Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.: One or
>   more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings. It must
>   match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain
>   of one of the App's domains.

I'm attaching my settings for my app.

[image: FaceBook app Settings]

http://dev.vibecheck.com:8080/vibecheckdata/vibeCheck

I have changed my host files and added an entry which maps to dev.vibecheck.com Any clues why I'm getting this error ?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with an setting in advanced Panel. The Oauth re-direction URL had a different domain than the one which I was running it on. So Please make sure that all the domains and the all the URLs you have match.